# Installing different OS

Tags: windows

After I installed ubuntu I tried to install windows back, around 3 weeks after. Now every time I try to reinstall Windows it says:

"Please insert proper boot device"

After uninstalling ubuntu it is still a boot partition in the bios. Does anyone know how I could install Windows back? The only reason why I want to do this is because Ubuntu can't play many games and I am a PC gamer.

Comment: Sorry, you should ask this on a windows forum. This site is about Ubuntu. Not about installing windows.

Comment: I think that the most acceptable reason of closure is off-topic, not duplicated @Mitch since the problem is within the Windows installation